# How to get JSON keys and add extra fields?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to get the key of these json objects in order to create a new object with extra filed to create table headers in a React app. JSON data:

```
let example = [
  {
    id: 1,
    city: 'New York',
  },
 {
    id: 2,
    city: 'Paris',
  },
]
```

The function:

```
getKeys() {
    return example.map((key) => {
      return {
        cityName: key, // gets the whole array
        capital: false,
      };
    });
  }
```

I tries `Object.keys( example);`, it returns integers; 0, 1.
How can I get the keys in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map the keys for an array since `example` is an array. If the data are consistent throughout the array get the first element `example[0]` and do `Object.keys()`.
So `Object.keys(example[0])`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to get the keys if you just want to add a property to the items in the array. I think there's a misunderstanding about .map, which gives you a single item/object in the array, not the keys.

Something like this perhaps?

```js
let example = [{
  id: 1,
  city: 'New York',
}, {
  id: 2,
  city: 'Paris',
}];

const modifiedArray = function(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      cityName: item.city,
      capital: false,
    }; 
  })  
}

const newArray = modifiedArray (example);

console.log(newArray )
```